# Remove existing content AND append new

Tags: javascript, jquery

This event proceed when the user clickz on an `albumPreview` element. This works well, when I click on each `albumPreview` once but when I click again it only removea, not append again.

`replaceWIth()` method doesn't work because of random number of elements in each `albumPreview`. How can I make this work?

```js
if ($('.img-container-wrap').length == 0) { //IF NOT EXIST, CREATE
    console.log(photoArray.response.length);
    for (i; i < photoArray.response.length; ++i) {
        albumContent //CONTAINER FOT IMAGES
        .append($("<div class='img-container-wrap'></div>")
                .append($("<div class='img-container'></div>") //APPEND TO IMG-CONTAINER-WRAP
                        .css({
                            "background-image": 'url("' + photoArray.response[i].src + '")'
                        })))
    }
} else if ($('.img-container-wrap').length > 0) { //IF EXIST, REMOVE _AND_ APPEND NEW CONTENT
    $(".album-content-section").find('.img-container-wrap').remove(); //REMOVE ELEMENTS
    for (i; i < photoArray.response.length; ++i) {
        albumContent //CONTAINER FOR IMAGES
        .append($("<div class='img-container-wrap'></div>")
                .append($("<div class='img-container'></div>")
                        .css({
                            "background-image": 'url("' + photoArray.response[i].src + '")'
                        })))
    }
```

Comment: .html('').append. The .html('') will clear the html in the container and append will add the new html

Comment: @Van why not use `empty()` instead of `html('')`?

Comment: Yes it will accomplish the same thing and is probably the better option. But both work.

Comment: you can simply do `.html('newhtml')`, why bother with append at all?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Should i put `empty()` in `for` loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand where my mistake is : `empty()` was in `for` loop.But `photoArray.response.length`is not infinity, and when loop finish, `empty()` method stop working.Thanks for all of you, guys!

Answer (score 0):

Empty your container first then do your loop:

```
albumContent.empty(); // remove previous content

for (i = 0; i < photoArray.response.length; i++) {
    albumContent //CONTAINER FOT IMAGES
        .append($("<div class='img-container-wrap'></div>")
            .append($("<div class='img-container'></div>") //APPEND TO IMG-CONTAINER-WRAP
                .css({
                    "background-image": 'url("' + photoArray.response[i].src + '")'
                })))
}
```

Comment: Sorry, same result as mine.